# LibreOffice Base sub form with multiple rows displayed

Tags: libreoffice-base

How do I show multiple lines in my sub-form?

For example, my main form is a prospect, with the sub-form recording and displaying one or more activity. After creating the sub-form, only one line is displayed at a time.